# No puedo ver los controles asp:button,etc, al cargar la página

Tags: asp.net

No sé por que pero de repente al darle play a la página web que estoy haciendo con visual studio 2015, no se me muestran todo lo que he hecho con asp, solo los tag html corrientes y no solo en una página, me pasa en todas los .aspx que tiene el proyecto. Alguno sabe a que puede deberse?

---

Me refiero a que con este código:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">



    <h2  id="h2_iniciarSesion" style="margin-top:2em;">Iniciar sesión</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <section id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <hr />
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false">
                        <p class="text-danger">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                        </p>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Login" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">CIF</asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Login" CssClass="form-control" ToolTip="Introduce un digito que empiece o acabe por una letra y lo demas sean 8 numeros" Text ="11111111a" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Login"
                                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="El campo CIF no puede estar vacío." Display="Dynamic" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Login"
                                ErrorMessage="Introduce un digito que empiece o acabe por una letra y lo demas sean 8 numeros." ForeColor="#B94A48" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{8}[a-z]{1}|[a-z]{1}[0-9]{8}" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Contraseña</asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control"  Text ="1111"  />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="El campo Contraseña no puede estar vacío." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe">Recordarme?</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="LogIn" Text="Iniciar sesión" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <p>

                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="ForgotPasswordHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/Account/OlvidarContraseña.aspx" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Olvidó su contraseña?</asp:HyperLink>

                </p>
            </section>
        </div>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

El navegador solo me muestra el primer `<h2>`, es decir Iniciar sesión. Todo el login no me lo muestra, y antes sí me lo mostraba correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Los controles `<asp:...>` se quedan en el servidor, que los convierte a tags `html`, que es lo que ve el navegador y lo que realmente entiende.

Por eso se llaman, controles de servidor y en su tag aparece `runat=server`

Te dejo el enlace a la [documentación de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zsyt68f1(v=vs.100).aspx) sobre estos controles.

Answer (score 0):

Ese es el comportamiento esperado, así funciona `ASP.NET`, el compilador de `.net` los convierte para que todos los exploradores webs los puedan entender.

Saludos.